# Laravel - Como chamar um action diferente do store,update, edit?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, controller, route, laravel-rotas

Criei um `action` sem ser os padrão do `resource`, como posso chamar o mesmo por um action no `form` assim como chamo o `update` e `store`.

```
<form method="POST" role="form" action="{!!URL::route('cadastro.store')!!}" >
```

quero chamar uma consulta quando clicar exemplo

```
<form method="POST" role="form" action="{!!URL('cadastro.consulta')!!}">
```

Comment: Qual é o nome do `Controller` e qual é o nome do Método (`Action`)?

Comment: cadastrarController e o action que quero chamar e consulta,     public function pesquisar(Request $request)
    {
        $nome= $request['nome'];
       
        $clientes= cadastroCliente::
            where('nome','like', "%".$nome."%")->get();
        return view('clientes.index', compact('clientes'));
    }

Comment: Pronto, acredito que seja isso !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abre o arquivo de rotas e crie um `Route::post` da seguinte maneira:

```
Route::post('consulta', [
    'as' => 'cadastro.consulta', 
    'uses' => 'cadastrarController@pesquisar']
);
```

***Referencia:***

- [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)
- [basic-routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: faço o action action="{!!URL::route(cadastro.pesquisa')!!}"  ? ou tem alguma alteração?

Comment: você tem que colocar a configuração que está na chave `'as'` que no caso eu coloquei na resposta `cadastro.consulta` consequentemente `action="{!!URL::route('cadastro.consulta')!!}"`. Se quiser mudar o nome é só mudar na chave `'as'` !!!

Comment: Funcionouu, tu pode me explicar? não achei nada parecido por ai

Comment: Você tem alguma dúvida especifica? por exemplo essa `as` e `uses`  são bem explicados nesse [link](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes). Dependendo da versão na documentação não tem explicação, mas, nas antigas tem que foi esse link que eu postei pra ti.

Comment: o `use` deve ser um nome único, para ser atribuir na chamada da sua `route('nome_da_rota')`.